# Error al intentar cerrar una aplicación

Tags: java, android

Buenas, estoy tratando de cerrar una app, pero al darle salir me cierra la actividad y me la vuelve a abrir.

En el logcat me sale esto:

`Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed`.

Estoy usando estos códigos:

```
private void salir()
    {
        final CharSequence[] option = {"Sí","No"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
        builder.setTitle("¿Desea salir?");
        builder.setItems(option, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (option[which]=="Sí"){
                    finishAffinity();
                }
                else if(option[which] == "No"){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }





@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown (int KeyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(KeyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            salir();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(KeyCode,event);
    }
```

Comment: Y donde esta el código donde tratas de salir de la actividad (por ejemplo usando `finish()`)?

Comment: En ves de `finish` uso `finishAffinity();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de hacer un `@Override` de `onKeyDown()` que no evita la ejecución normal de `onBackPressed()`, para crear un dialogo confirmando el cierre (por apretar "atras") deberías hacer un `@Override` de `onBackPressed`, llamando al dialogo, y dependiente del resultado llamas a `finish()` de la actividad.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    salir();
}
```

y en salir con la opción "Sí" llamas a:

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

Así quedas en la normalidad de Android.

Comment: Pero si lo que quiero es cerrar toda la aplicación?

Comment: Si quieres luego de la confirmación cerrar todas las actividades de tu app, puedes seguir [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001963/finish-all-activities-at-a-time). Basicamente llamas a una nueva actividad usando el flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` y en `onCreate(Bundle data)` llamas a `finish()`.

Comment: Pura vida!! amiga gracias.

Comment: Como amiga seria bien feo. (Bueno - fea en este caso) ;) Si te sirve la respuesta puedes aceptarla también.

Comment: Lo siento XD, eso fue un dedaso XD

Comment: Y si me funcionó su respuesta amigo, pero mi error esta en otra parte, es un hilo en segundo plano que no puedo finalizar.